# How can i display my data in database and export it to pdf -Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

my x variable is getting all the data in my database, i guess? someone help me how can i display all data and export it to pdf file.

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="WishList.pdf"'

buffer = BytesIO()

# Create the PDF object, using the BytesIO object as its "file."
p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)
x = Item.objects.all()

p.drawString(100, 100,x)

p.drawString(200,300,"sad")

# Close the PDF object cleanly.
p.showPage()
p.save()

# Get the value of the BytesIO buffer and write it to the response.
pdf = buffer.getvalue()
buffer.close()
response.write(pdf)
return response
```

Comment: Assuming you referred to the code on the Django [site docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/outputting-pdf/#write-your-view) which suggests that they use the [ReportLab API](http://www.reportlab.com/) to generate PDFs, you should further investigate into how you want to write your data to the file using the API.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable x won't return anything you can print into the PDF, because its a queryset and not a couple strings attached to each other. I just started working with Django and getting the values works something like this:

```
x = Item.objects.all[0].name
```

This code snippet will assign the vale of the row name of the first entry in your Item table to the variable x.

For more Information I can only recommend reading the [Tutorial about writing queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysetshttp://) on the django website.