# pdf file doesn't save in Django

Tags: python, django

I use Django 2.1.4 and use Django sample for create pdf report

```
def some_view(request):
    # Create a file-like buffer to receive PDF data.
    buffer = io.BytesIO()

    # Create the PDF object, using the buffer as its "file."
    p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)

    # Draw things on the PDF. Here's where the PDF generation happens.
    # See the ReportLab documentation for the full list of functionality.
    p.drawString(100, 100, "Hello world.")

    # Close the PDF object cleanly, and we're done.
    p.showPage()
    p.save()

    # FileResponse sets the Content-Disposition header so that browsers
    # present the option to save the file.
    return FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename='hello.pdf')
```

It started dowloaded but never finished. What is wrong?
Old version works properly

```
def some_view(request):
    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate PDF headers.
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.pdf"'

    # Create the PDF object, using the response object as its "file."
    p = canvas.Canvas(response)

    # Draw things on the PDF. Here's where the PDF generation happens.
    # See the ReportLab documentation for the full list of functionality.
    p.drawString(100, 100, "Hello world.")

    # Close the PDF object cleanly, and we're done.
    p.showPage()
    p.save()
    return response
```

Answer (score 2):

I would look at this example (except for the queryset),, see if that works, similar worked for me earlier today, [How can i display my data in database and export it to pdf -Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072058/how-can-i-display-my-data-in-database-and-export-it-to-pdf-django)

> Get the value of the BytesIO buffer and write it to the response.

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="WishList.pdf"'
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas 
buffer = BytesIO()
p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)
p.drawString(100, 100, "Hello world.")
p.showPage()
p.save()
pdf = buffer.getvalue()
buffer.close()
response.write(pdf)
return response
```

Comment: This worked for me, while the example at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/outputting-pdf/#install-reportlab didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, the old version is the way I recommend that you do it.  To get this working with a `FileResponse`, try the below:

```
# FileResponse sets the Content-Disposition header so that browsers
# present the option to save the file.
response = FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename='hello.pdf', content_type='application/pdf')
# set the content length to let the browser know how many bytes to expect
response['Content-Length'] = bugger.getbuffer().nbytes
return response
```