# Export pdf file

Tags: django

Please help me  i just want to export pdf file i am stuck with qs variable i dont know how to type i searched but could not find complete answer.

views.py

```
 import io
 from django.http import FileResponse
 from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas


def export_page(request):
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)
    qs = Add.objects.all[0]
    p.drawString(100, 100, qs)
    p.showPage()
    p.save()
    buffer.seek(0)
    return FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename='hello.pdf')
```

Comment: qs= Item.objects.all[0].name    ...................  i found this code but i dont know how to use it ,

Comment: You are not explaining at all what you're trying to do. What should be in the PDF? What is `Item`? What is `canvas`? What does `p.drawString()` do, which is where the `qs` is used?

Comment: i want to export data as pdf file ,

Comment: qs will get all objects from database and i want it in pdf format

Comment: @MuhammedBilal using which libraries?

Comment: well, yes, `qs` is the list of all `Item` objects. So your code is correct. But since we don't know what you're using to generate the pdf (we don't know what is `canvas` and thus we don't know what `drawString` is expecting) there's no way we can tell you if passing `qs` to `drawString` is correct or not. Also, you're not explaining what's wrong with your current code. Does it raise an error? Or does it display something weird?

Comment: I am not getting converted pdf file

Comment: https://django.readthedocs.io/en/2.2.x/howto/outputting-pdf.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072058/how-can-i-display-my-data-in-database-and-export-it-to-pdf-django

Comment: `drawString()` expects a string. `qs` is a list of instances of your `Item` model (actually a queryset, but once executed it's a list). What part of each `Item` do you want to display in the PDF?

Comment: budget = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
 expense = models.IntegerField(default=0)
 date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True, blank=True)

Comment: Budget expense date .

Comment: try looping through the objects in your queryset and build a string by adding all of this information to the string. Start with `first_item = Item.objects.first()` and `p.drawString(f"{first_item.budget}")` and you should see something in your pdf, then extend the code to make a longer string containing everything you want.

Comment: Can you give example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I created new utils.py file**

```
using python 3
pip install --pre xhtml2pdf 


    from io import BytesIO
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.template.loader import get_template

    from xhtml2pdf import pisa

    def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
        template = get_template(template_src)
        html  = template.render(context_dict)
        result = BytesIO()
        pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
        if not pdf.err:
            return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
        return None



**VIEWS.PY** 

    from .utils import render_to_pdf # FOR PDF EXPORT
    from django.template.loader import get_template #FOR PDF EXPORT


    def pdf_view(request, *args, **kwargs):   #FOR PDF EXPORT
        template = get_template('invoice.html')
        qs = Add.objects.all()
        context = {'qs':qs}
        html  = template.render(context)
        pdf  = render_to_pdf('invoice.html', context)
        if pdf:
            return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf') # TILL HERE HTML TO PDF 
        return HttpResponse("Not found")
```

**html page**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PDF EXPORT </title>
  <body>

        {% for i in qs %}   
        <div class='details'>
            budget:{{ i.budget }}<br/>
            expense: {{ i.expense }} <br/>
            Date:{{ i.date }}<br/>
            Name: {{i.business}}
            <hr class='hrItem' />
        </div>
        {% endfor %}


    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/html-template-to-pdf-in-django/